# Ajax request to pass value to rails controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've been struggling most of the day to try figure out how to make this work. I'm using the bootstrap pager method to provide 'next', 'previous', and 'take quiz' buttons for a language learning website I've been playing around with. I've gotten the javascript and ajax working such that when I click the buttons a page refresh is not required and I can also detect when a particular button is clicked.

What I'm having difficulty doing is submitting another ajax request to pass information back to my rails controller. For instance if the next button or take quiz button is clicked it increments a variable that I then need to use to update my database with and the server side. The previous button does the same but decrements the variable.

Here is my JS:

```
    $(function() {

function nextHandler() {
gon.bookmark = gon.bookmark + 1; #using gon gem and bookmark is a column in my DB

} 

function previousHandler() {
 gon.bookmark = gon.bookmark - 1; #using gon gem and bookmark is a column in my DB
}  

function takeQuizHandler() {
 gon.bookmark = gon.bookmark + 1; #using gon gem and bookmark is a column in my DB
}  

$(".Next").click(nextHandler);
$(".Previous").click(previousHandler);
$(".TakeQuiz").click(takeQuizHandler);
});
```

Heres my view file:

```
   <div class="center hero-unit">

    <%= @word.english %>, <%= @word.english_to_spanish %>



    <% if @lastDigit == 0 %>
      <ul class="pager">

        <li class="Previous"><a href="/langs/<%= @wordBM - 1 %>">Previous</a></li>


        <li class="TakeQuiz"><a href="/langs/<%= @wordBM + 1 %>">Take Quiz</a></li>

      </ul>
    <% elsif @lastDigit == 1 %>
      <ul class="pager">

        <li class ="Next"><a href="/langs/<%= @wordBM + 1 %>">Next</a></li>

      </ul>
    <% else %>
      <ul class="pager">

        <li class="Previous"><a href="/langs/<%= @wordBM - 1 %>">Previous</a></li>


        <li class="Next"><a href="/langs/<%= @wordBM + 1 %>">Next</a></li>

      </ul>
    <% end %>

    </div>
```

And here is my langs controller:

```
class LangsController < ApplicationController


  def show
    @word = Lang.find(params[:id])

    @wordBM = current_user.bookmark

    gon.bookmark = @wordBM

    digitArray = @wordBM.to_s.split('')
    lastIndex = digitArray.length - 1
    @lastDigit = digitArray[lastIndex].to_i


  end

end
```

Any help is much appreciated and if I'm going about it all wrong please let me know. I'm definitely a rails noob.